# how to insert table in quill editor

Tags: reactjs

```
import quillTable from "quill-table";
// Quill.debug("warn");
// Quill.register("modules/ImageResize", ImageResize);
Quill.register("modules/ImageCompress", ImageCompress);
Quill.register("modules/imageUploader", imageUploader);

Quill.register(quillTable.TableCell);
Quill.register(quillTable.TableRow);
Quill.register(quillTable.Table);
Quill.register(quillTable.Contain);
Quill.register("modules/table", quillTable.TableModule);

// [TableContainer, TableRow, TableCell, 0]

var maxRows = 10;
var maxCols = 5;
var tableOptions = [];
for (var r = 1; r <= maxRows; r++) {
  for (var c = 1; c <= maxCols; c++) {
    tableOptions.push("newtable_" + r + "_" + c);
  }
}
```

How can we add table to React-Quill text editor using quill-better-table . Can someone provide existing codesandbox for same if availablere or changes need in react-Quill to allow us to add table .